# How to moves the divs by clicking on each one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to when I click on every div 
 It's the first to be in front of  everyone and the others div are moved.for example div4 is in front of everyone.when I click on div1 I want to put div1 in place of div4 and Then again, on each one that I click on, it's the front but My code does not work properly after several times and does not display one of the shapes.

```js
$(".haml-category").click(function() {
  var top = $(this).data("top");
  var zindex = $(this).data("zindex");
  var temp = $(".haml-category-container").find(".selected");
  $(".haml-category-container").find(".selected").removeClass("selected").data("zindex", zindex).data("top", top).css({
    "z-index": zindex,
    "top": top
  });
  $(this).data("zindex", temp.data("zindex")).data("top", temp.data("top")).addClass("selected");

});
```

```css
.haml-category-container {
  position: relative;
background-color:#ccc;
}

.haml-category {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: top 1s;
}

.sec-saheb-bar {
  z-index: 0;
}

.sec-ranande {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 40px;
}

.sec-barbar {
  z-index: 2;
  top: 85px;
}

.sec-bazaryab {
  z-index: 3;
  top: 130px;
}

.selected {
  z-index: 3;
  top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="haml-category-container">
  <div class="haml-category sec-saheb-bar" id="sec-saheb-bar" data-zindex="0" data-top="0">
    <h6>div1</h6>
    <p> content div1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="haml-category sec-ranande" id="sec-ranande" data-zindex="1" data-top="40">
    <h6>div2</h6>
    <p> content div2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="haml-category sec-barbar" id="sec-barbar" data-zindex="2" data-top="85">
    <h6>div3</h6>
    <p> content div3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="haml-category sec-bazaryab selected" id="sec-bazaryab" data-zindex="3" data-top="130">
    <h6>div4</h6>
    <p> content div4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you mean by `move`? Is it drag & drop?

Comment: No ,I mean the movement is just up and down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable temp may has be changed,modified as below.

```js
$(".haml-category").click(function() {
  var top = $(this).data("top");
  var zindex = $(this).data("zindex");
  var temp = $(".haml-category-container").find(".selected");
  var top2 = temp.data("top");
  var zindex2 = temp.data("zindex");
  $(this).data("zindex", zindex2).data("top", top2).css({
    "z-index": zindex2,
    "top": top2
  }).addClass("selected");
  temp.removeClass("selected").data("zindex", zindex).data("top", top);
  temp.css({
    "z-index": zindex,
    "top": top
  });

});
```

```css
.haml-category-container {
  position: relative;
}

.haml-category {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: top 1s;
}

.sec-saheb-bar {
  z-index: 0;
}

.sec-ranande {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 40px;
}

.sec-barbar {
  z-index: 2;
  top: 85px;
}

.sec-bazaryab {
  z-index: 3;
  top: 130px;
}

.selected {
  z-index: 3;
  top: 130px;
}
#sec-saheb-bar{
  background-color:#0077CC;
}
#sec-ranande{
  background-color:#1F1D1C;
}
#sec-barbar{
  background-color:#FECD45;
}
#sec-bazaryab{
  background-color:#1AA160;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="haml-category-container">
  <div class="haml-category sec-saheb-bar" id="sec-saheb-bar" data-zindex="0" data-top="0">
    <h6>div1</h6>

  </div>
  <div class="haml-category sec-ranande" id="sec-ranande" data-zindex="1" data-top="40">
    <h6>div2</h6>

  </div>
  <div class="haml-category sec-barbar" id="sec-barbar" data-zindex="2" data-top="85">
    <h6>div3</h6>

  </div>
  <div class="haml-category sec-bazaryab selected" id="sec-bazaryab" data-zindex="3" data-top="130">
    <h6>div4</h6>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this FRANKENSTEIN's monster in 2010 for testing purpose.how you can see i put everywhere z-index:9  watch the demo try to drag every element over other element.with some modifications you can convert it in jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<style></style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
// function returns array of box bounds
 box_offset = function (box) {
  var scrollPosition = getScrollPosition(), // get scroll position
   oLeft = 0,// - scrollPosition[0],   // define offset left (take care of horizontal scroll position)
   oTop  = 0,// - scrollPosition[1],   // define offset top (take care od vertical scroll position)
   box_old = box;       // remember box object
  // loop to the root element and return box offset (top, right, bottom, left)
  do {
   oLeft += box.offsetLeft;
   oTop += box.offsetTop;
   box = box.offsetParent;
  }
  while (box);
  // return box offset array
  //       top               right,                     bottom             left
  //return [ oTop, oLeft + box_old.offsetWidth, oTop + box_old.offsetHeight, oLeft ];
  //       top               right,                     bottom             left
  return [
    oLeft,
    oLeft + box_old.offsetWidth,
    oTop,
    oTop + box_old.offsetHeight
    ];
 };


 
 // function returns scroll positions in array
 getScrollPosition = function () {
  // define local scroll position variables
  var scrollX, scrollY;
  // Netscape compliant
  if (typeof(window.pageYOffset) === 'number') {
   scrollX = window.pageXOffset;
   scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
  }
  // DOM compliant
  else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop)) {
   scrollX = document.body.scrollLeft;
   scrollY = document.body.scrollTop;
  }
  // IE6 standards compliant mode
  else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop)) {
   scrollX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
   scrollY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
  // needed for IE6 (when vertical scroll bar was on the top)
  else {
   scrollX = scrollY = 0;
  }
  // return scroll positions
  return [ scrollX, scrollY ];
 };


  //-->
  </SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--


swdrag = false;
var picwidth;
var picheight;
var picxpos;
var picypos;


var Drag = {

 obj : null,
 
 init : function(o, resizer, oRoot, minX, maxX, minY, maxY, bSwapHorzRef, bSwapVertRef, fXMapper, fYMapper)
 {
  o.onmousedown = Drag.start;
  o.resizer = resizer;
  o.root = o;
  
  if ( isNaN(parseInt(o.root.style.left  ))) o.root.style.left   = "0px";
  if ( isNaN(parseInt(o.root.style.top   ))) o.root.style.top    = "0px";
  
  o.root.onDragStart = new Function();
  o.root.onDragEnd = new Function();
  o.root.onDrag  = new Function();
  calculate();
 },

 start : function(e)
 {
  var o = Drag.obj = this;
  e = Drag.fixE(e);
  var y = parseInt( o.root.style.top  );
  var x = parseInt( o.root.style.left );
  o.root.onDragStart(x, y);
  o.lastMouseX = e.clientX;
  o.lastMouseY = e.clientY;
  
  document.onmousemove = Drag.drag;
  document.onmouseup  = Drag.end;
  calculate();
  return false;
 },

 drag : function(e)
 {
  e = Drag.fixE(e);
  var o = Drag.obj;
  
  var nx, ny;
  var ey = e.clientY;
  var ex = e.clientX;
  var changeX = (ex - o.lastMouseX);
  var changeY = (ey - o.lastMouseY);
  

  
  
  nx = parseInt(o.root.style.left ) + changeX;
  ny = parseInt(o.root.style.top  ) + changeY;
  
  if (o.xMapper)  nx = o.xMapper(y)
  else if (o.yMapper) ny = o.yMapper(x)
  
  Drag.obj.root.style["left"] = nx + "px";
  Drag.obj.root.style["top"] = ny + "px";
  Drag.obj.lastMouseX = ex;
  Drag.obj.lastMouseY = ey;
  
  Drag.obj.root.onDrag(nx, ny);
  
  Drag.xmouse = Drag.obj.lastMouseX;
  Drag.ymouse = Drag.obj.lastMouseY;
  
  Drag.xmouse = e.clientX;
  Drag.ymouse = e.clientY;
  calculate();
  calculate2();
  swdrag=true;
  
  
  return false;
 },

 end : function()
 {
  document.onmousemove = null;
  document.onmouseup   = null;
  Drag.obj.root.onDragEnd( parseInt(Drag.obj.root.style["right"]), 
         parseInt(Drag.obj.root.style["bottom"]));
  Drag.obj = null;
  calculate();
  if (swdrag){
   swdrag = false;
  }
  

 },

 fixE : function(e)
 {
  if (typeof e == 'undefined') e = window.event;
  if (typeof e.layerX == 'undefined') e.layerX = e.offsetX;
  if (typeof e.layerY == 'undefined') e.layerY = e.offsetY;
  Drag.xmouse=e.clientX;
  Drag.ymouse=e.clientY;
  calculate();
  return e;
 },
 xmouse:0,
 ymouse:0
};
 
function start(){
 IMAGE.style.left=x_pic_ini;
 IMAGE.style.top=y_pic_ini;
 //calculate();
}


function calculate(){
 widthIMAGE=parseInt(IMAGE.clientWidth);
picwidth=widthIMAGE;
 heightIMAGE=parseInt(IMAGE.clientHeight);
picheight=heightIMAGE;
 
 xposex=parseInt(IMAGE.style.left);
 yposex=parseInt(IMAGE.style.top);
 picxpos=xposex;
 picypos=yposex;
 IMAGE.left=picxpos;
 IMAGE.top=picypos;
 
}

function calculate2(){
 oobj=document.f1; 
 oobj.xpic.value=picxpos;
 oobj.ypic.value=picypos;

 //fiecare celula | every box
 if(lastbox!=null)
 {
  //lastbox.style.background='white';
  //lastbox.style.color='black';
 }
 

 mxrows=document.getElementById("tb1").rows.length;
 
 for(i=0;i<mxrows;i++){
  mxcols=document.getElementById("tb1").rows[i].cells.length;
  for(u=0;u<3;u++){
   //a("i"+i+u+"=");
   theboxobj=eval(document.getElementById("i"+i+u));
   xyb=box_offset(theboxobj);
   oox=picxpos;
   ooy=picypos+(heightIMAGE-theboxobj.clientHeight)/2;
   if ((oox>xyb[0])&&(oox<xyb[1])&&(ooy>xyb[2])&&(ooy<xyb[3]))
   {
    a('i('+i+' '+u+')');
    theboxobj.style.background='red';
    theboxobj.style.color='yellow';
       lastbox=theboxobj;
    
 
if(!swdrag){
break;

//  imobj=document.getElementById("image");
  //document.write(obj2(obj,'obj'));
//  oldobj=imobj.outerHTML;
// imobj=new Object();
// lastbox.appendChild(imobj);
 lastbox.parentNode.removeChild(lastbox);
 //imobj=new Object();
 lastbox.parentNode.appendChild(imobj);
 lastbox.parentNode.outerHTML='<td>xx</td>';
// imobj.parentNode.removeChild(imobj);
// lastbox.innerHTML=oldobj;
 }

//alert(oldobj);

    break;
   }
  }
 }
}

//-->
</SCRIPT>


<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
//---------------obj 2 --------------------------------
function obj2(obj, obj_name) {
   var result = "";
   for (var i in obj)
      result += obj_name + "." + i + " = " + obj[i] +'-'+typeof obj[i]+ "\n<br>\n";
   return result
}
function obj1(obj,txt){//obj(this.style)
 tt=document.open('about:blank','here','');
 tt.document.write(obj2(obj,txt));
}
//-----------------------------------------------------
//-->
</SCRIPT>



<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--

ids=new Array();
ids[0]='dsdsad';
ids[1]='tre1';
ids[2]='image';
ids[3]='image2';
ids[4]='newd';
ids[5]='txt';





 function overb(obj){
  color='#FF0000';
  width='3px';
  obj.style.borderTopWidth = width;
  obj.style.borderTopColor =color;
  obj.style.borderTopStyle ='solid';
  
  obj.style.borderLeftWidth = width;
  obj.style.borderLeftColor =color;
  obj.style.borderLeftStyle ='solid';

  obj.style.borderRightWidth = width;
  obj.style.borderRightColor =color;
  obj.style.borderRightStyle ='solid';

  obj.style.borderBottomWidth = width;
  obj.style.borderBottomColor =color;
  obj.style.borderBottomStyle ='solid';

  obj.style.zIndex='999';


  off=box_offset(obj);
  x_pic_ini=off[0];
  y_pic_ini=off[2];
  IMAGE=document.getElementById(obj.id);
  //obj1(IMAGE,'IMAGE');
  Drag.init(IMAGE);
  start();
 }

 function outb(obj){
  obj.style.borderTopWidth = '0px'; 
  obj.style.borderLeftWidth = '0px';
  obj.style.borderRightWidth = '0px';
  obj.style.borderBottomWidth = '0px';
  obj.style.zIndex='9'
 }

//-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="">

<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="#" NAME="f1">

<div style="position:absolute;left:50;top:50;z-index:9;" 
onmouseover="overb(this);doit(this)" onmouseout="outb(this);" id="canalica">xpic<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="xpic"></div>

<div style="position:absolute;left:50;top:75;z-index:9;" onmouseover="overb(this);doit(this)" onmouseout="outb(this);" id="tre1">ypic<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="ypic"></div>

<div style="position:absolute;left:50;top:75;z-index:9;" onmouseover="overb(this);doit(this)" onmouseout="outb(this);" id="submit">ypic<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" value="submit"></div>


</FORM><HR>

<div style="position:absolute;left:50;top:150;z-index:9;border-top:1px solid green;" onmouseover="overb(this);doit(this)" onmouseout="outb(this);" id="image">Yes!</div>

<div style="position:absolute;left:50;top:150;z-index:9;border-top:1px solid green;" onmouseover="overb(this);doit(this);" onmouseout="outb(this);" id="image2">yep yep !</div>



<div style="position:absolute;left:50;top:150;z-index:9;border-top:1px solid green;" onmouseover="overb(this);/*document.write(obj2(this.style,'this.style'));*/doit(this)" onmouseout="outb(this);" id="newd"><TABLE border="1px" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0" WIDTH="500" id="tb1" align="left" style="margin:0;">
  <TR>
 <TD id="i00">11</TD>
 <TD id="i01">12</TD>
 <TD id="i02">13</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
 <TD id="i10">21</TD>
 <TD id="i11">22</TD>
 <TD id="i12">23</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
 <TD id="i20">31</TD>
 <TD id="i21">32</TD>
 <TD id="i22">33</TD>
  </TR>
  </TABLE></div>
  <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="#" NAME="f3">
 <TEXTAREA style="position:absolute;left:50;top:175;z-index:9;" onmouseover="overb(this);doit(this)" onmouseout="outb(this);" id="txt" NAME="aa" ROWS="20" COLS="20"></TEXTAREA>
  </FORM>




  <BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>

  <script type="text/javascript">
//-----------------------------------------------------

 var x_pic_ini, y_pic_ini,IMAGE;
 function doit(obj){

  
 }
//------------------------------------------------------
</script>




<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
/* for(i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
 oo=document.getElementById(ids[i]);
 //obj1(oo,'oo');
 oo.style.Left=i*20;
 oo.style.Top=i*20;
 //alert(ids[i]);
 
}*/
//-->
</SCRIPT>




<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--


function a(val){
 ww=document.f3.aa.value+val;
 document.f3.aa.value=ww;
}


 var div1=document.getElementById("newd");
 div1.style.left=600;
 div1.style.top=200;

 //fiecare celula
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  for(u=0;u<3;u++){
   a("i"+i+u+"=");
   a(box_offset(eval(document.getElementById("i"+i+u)))+'\n');
  }
 }
 var lastbox=null;
 //doar div-ul..
 //alert(box_offset(div1));
//-->
</SCRIPT>


</BODY></HTML>
```